# Share the UIs between electron desktop with ionic app

Tags: c, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, electron

I have a Android app write with ionic, and it will call some C functions with Cordova.

Now, I need to make the same app to the Desktop. I want to use Electron. and the C code can run as nodejs C/C++ addon in electron. but if i use the ionic in electron. I will got following error when load the nodejs addon:

**Module parse failed: XXX.node Unexpected character''(1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type (Source code omitted for this binary file)**

The XXX.node is the C library binary file.

I google some days, and found someone said that Node runs on the server side. Ionic is client side, so ionic can't call the node modules. Is that right?

If that is right, How can i use the same UIs code? I need to rewrite one or use other framework?

Thanks!